# Vector3.magnitude and vector3.normalized explanation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am looking at this code and do not know what is this `magnitude` and `normalized`doing and how is this guy using them. In documentation there is only few thing but it doesn't explain much.

Code i am looking at is:

```
public float minDistance = 1.0f;
public float maxDistance = 4.0f;
public float smooth = 10.0f;
Vector3 dollyDir;
public Vector3 dollyDirAdjusted;
public float distance;

void Awake()
{
    dollyDir = transform.localPosition.normalized;
    //What has he got with this? Documentation says Returns this vector with
    //a magnitude of 1 so if i get it it return's it's length as 1. So what is the point?

    distance = transform.localPosition.magnitude;
    //Have no idea what he got with this
}
void Update()
{
    Vector3 desiredPos = transform.parent.TransformPoint(dollyDir * maxDistance);
    //I know what TransfromPoint does but what is he getting with this dollyDir * maxDistance

    //Some other code which i understand
}
```

And while i am here if someone could explain me `Mathf.Clamp`

Documentation for `clamp` is so unclear and how i got it is that i give top and bottom value `1 and 5` and if i set `value = 3` it will return 3, but if i set value > 5 it will return 5 and if i set value < 1 it will return 1?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a suggestion, as it is extremely useful for 3D applications, you should try and learn some linear algebra. Khan Academy has [a decent course](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra) on it.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting into it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vector3.magnitude returns a float, its a single dimensional value expressing vector length (so it looses directional information)

Vector3.normalized is a bit of an opposite operation - it returns vector direction, guaranteeing that the magnitude of the resulting vector is one, (it preserves the direction information but looses the magnitude information).

The two are often useful for when you want to seperate those two ways of looking at a vector, for example if you need to have an influcence between two bodies where the influence is inversly proportional to the distance between them, you can do

```
float mag=(targetpos-mypos).magnitude;
if (mag<maxRange)
{
Vector3 dir=(targetpos-mypos).normalized;
Vector3 newVector=dir*(maxRange-mag);
}
```

this is the most typical use case for me, I am not sure what the author of the original code meant by his as it does seem he could just use a vector difference without using the two extra calls

Mathf.Clamp returns value of value lies between min and max, returns min if its lower and max if is greater.

Another interesting feature of Vector3 is sqrMagnitude which returns a^2+b^2+c^c without computhing the square root. While it adds a bit to the complexity to the code (you need to compare it with squared distance), it saves a relatively expensive root computation; The slightly optimised but a tiny bit harder to read version would look like this

```
Vectior3 delta=targetpos-mypos;
if (delta.sqrMagnitude<maxRange*maxRange)
 {
  Vector3 dir=delta.normalized;
  Vector3 newVector=dir*(maxRange-delta.magnitude);
}
```

Comment: I have got what is magnitude and normalized but i haven't got your code. Let's say maxRange = 15. If i calculate it good your `mag = 11,35` and `dir = (0.6, 0.7, -0.4)` and `newVector = (2.2, 2.6 ,-1.3)`. So now how the hell is this usable anywhere?

Comment: @AleksaRistic because you can use the normalized version of the vector to control its max range,  if you get the magnitude of the vector and it is greater then your max range for whatever reason, you can multiply the normalized version of the vector to get that information(aka end point within range).  both the normalized version, and the magnitude of a vector is useful in either lighting or collision algorithms.

Comment: Ohhh i get it now. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

A vector can be thought of as a direction and distance (although it is normally expressed as an amount in each axis; for example, +3 on *x* and -4 on *y* would have a magnitude of 5). A normalized vector has magnitude 1, so it is *just* the direction (+0.6,-0.8 for the +3,-4 example); the magnitude tells you the original distance part. You can then multiply a normalized vector (the direction) by *any* magnitude to express "go *this* far in *that* direction". In this case, they seem to be moving 4 units (`maxDistance`) in the same direction as the original vector.

Comment: Fck me if i understood second part. First is ok, i know now what is magnitude, how it is calculated and what it states for but second part with multiplying i haven't got. You are saying that with this normalized i can have magnitude 10 and from that get coords  by multiplying (so i get 6, 8?

Comment: @AleksaRistic there is no need for swearing, or even abbreviated swearing.

Comment: Sorry but i am upset when i cannot catch something :/

Comment: @AleksaRistic it's alright you will typically get a better response from people if you avoid it =)

Comment: @AleksaRistic yes, that's what you'd get - well, it would be 6, -8, but I think you get the key point

Answer (score 1):

A magnitude is the length of a vector from the origin. It is like using a tape measure from (0,0,0) to wherever your point is. A normalized vector is that same vector, but its length is exactly 1.
An important note is that the normalized vector is calculated is by dividing by its magnitude.